# getting error , imagick annotate+ adding text to the image,can nybdy help me?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $text=$_POST['text1'];

    $im1=$_POST['image'];

    echo $text;

    echo $im1;

    $im2 = new Imagick($im1);

    $im->annotateImage($im2, 0, 0, 0, $text);

    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');

    $thumbnail = $im->getImageBlob();

    header("Content-Type: $thumbnail");

    echo $thumbnail;

    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($thumbnail).'" />'; 
?>
```

Comment: i m posting text and image from the previous page

Comment: 1. image blob data is not a valid Content-Type. 2. you are outputting the image in both binary and html format at the same time (that's not going to work like that). 3. please show an example of what is posted for "image." is it a file path/url? an uploaded image file? 4. "getting error" is not helpful. describe the error or better yet, copy and paste the actual error message.

Comment: what is $im in this code

Comment: This question contains no question or problem description. Source code is not enough to get a solution

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<?php
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

?>
```

For further reference: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php